# Is program written in MONO as efficient as the program on .net framework

Tags: .net, mono

I am working on WPF. I have just discovered this MONO project and so, I am fresh to the MONO. I wanted to know that programs written on mono are as **fast** & **efficient** as the ones written on .net framework 4.0. does it use same JIT like compilation. If not is any research going on that also.

Comment: Does/will It satisfy the purpose of what .Net is developed for.
sorry if I am asking too beginner's questions.

Comment: Mono has two JIT backends with different performance characteristics. If you want faster code you need the LLVM backend.

Comment: A different JIT compiler that takes longer to compile but produces better code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Software you write will generally run on Mono with similar performance (it does implement a VM and JIT compiler just like .NET does), if you only use components that are also implemented in Mono, and therein lies the problem:

[Mono does *not* implement WPF!](http://www.mono-project.com/WPF)

Generally you will see, that Mono lacks support for a lot of the new any fancy Microsoft APIs like WPF, WCF and EntityFramework. Additionally, if you only want to develop for Windows, the .NET Framework is the way to go, it is a lot more polished and specifically designed for Windows. If you are a C#/VB developer who desperately wants to develop for Mac OS or Linux, it is worth taking a look at Mono - otherwise you can safely ignore it.

[Mono API Compatibility](http://www.mono-project.com/Compatibility)

Comment: WCF is partially supported and Microsoft open-sourced EntityFramework so Mono has that too (http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2012/Aug-13.html).

Answer (score 1):

Mono uses its own implementation of JIT, virtual machine etc. The main reason for using Mono is if you want to develop or port a managed program to Linux or OS X . If you are developing for Windows, use Visual Studio and the .net framework. It's very unlikely that Mono will be faster, but likely it will be buggier, especially for GUI design.

Another reason to use the MS .net is that it has been tested by so many people writing .Net programs, so you should have less trouble with the platform.

I speculate here a bit, but probably the only good reason to develop in Mono is if you want to port a program or a piece of a program to Linux or OS X. Most likely you will still need to do some work, but it's a start. Even so, I would look at porting the .net code to Java as Java has much better support on the other operating systems and there are tools and companies who do these sort of conversions.

Check out this question as well:

[Differences in development between .NET and Mono](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2783268/net-vs-mono-differences-in-development)