# Learning visual c# using monodevelop

Tags: c#, visual-studio, monodevelop

I intend to take a course in software development which focusses on Visual C#. The text book used is called "Beginning Visual C# 2012 Programming" and the material in this is built around Visual Studio.
I do not have access to a Windows computer. I am running Ubuntu and I have read that it is not possible to run Visual Studio via Wine.
Would it be possible to follow such a course using Monodevelop instead of Visual Studio?
I have installed Monodevelop and have compiled some of the sample code in the book, but can I assume that all the code from the book will compile? Are Visual Studio and Monodevelop that similar?

Comment: Similar SO question and answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2783268/differences-in-development-between-net-and-mono

Comment: Check the [class status pages](http://www.go-mono.com/status/) to look at mono vs. .NET.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. What I really wanted to know was, in your opinions, would I be able to follow a training course in basic Visual C# which is taught using VS, by using Monodevelop for the exercises instead of VS?

Answer (score 0):

**Microsoft Visual Studio** can only be used in Windows and intended use by Application Dev, Mobile Dev and Online Development. Its supported language are ASP.net, C, C++, C#, CSS, CSS3, HTML, HTML5 and Java Script. **Monodevelop** can be used in Android, iPhone or iOS, Linux, Mac, and Windows. and intended use by the same also with Microsoft Visual Studio. Its supported language are ASP.net, C, C++, C#, F#, HTML 5, Java. Yes they have similarities since MonoDevelop version is not updated and VS is he state of the art in terms of IDEs. I could really recommend you to use VS but your using Ubuntu so use MonoDevelop.