# C# .net / mono cross-platform differences?

Tags: c#, .net, mono, cross-platform

I've been searching for a while now trying to find an answer for this, basically if I create a visual studio app using .net c# and I want to port it to mac / linux,

1. Will there be and code I'll have to move around/change when switching to mono?
2. What things should I avoid doing while developing to make it easier to port later?
3. Is system.windows.forms usable in mono? Should I just use GTK#? Does it matter?

Comment: Possible a duplicate of [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2783268/differences-in-development-between-net-and-mono)...

Comment: There are far too many posts already on StackOverflow regarding this topic, so hope you can spare some time on each of them, instead of posting all over again.

Answer (score 1):

1. Not too much. but if your using any p invoke or library that do. they can't be used in mono. unless you rewrite/find a mono compatable one.
2. Stay away from propriety software's and APIs. Directx does not work. but there are ports for SDL/Opengl. Only pinvoke tools that exist on all platforms. and dont make mixed mode assembly's.
3. It is. but it does not look good on Linux/Mac. because well it looks like windows.