# What is the equivalent of Shell mono command for CLI?

Tags: command-line-interface

**Situation :**

I normally run executable with the MONO command (in shell)

Example :

```
mono stress.exe /d=1
```

**Problem :**

I tried to find the equivalent in CLI. I'm pretty sure it would be somewhere on that site but I didn't find it.

Comment: [(shell == CLI) or not](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4126/what-is-the-exact-difference-between-a-terminal-a-shell-a-tty-and-a-con?)? Please clarify.

Comment: I'm kinda lost in all of that. But I'm in the langage where variables need %% around them and I thought it was CLI (always called it like this) when Shell uses $

Comment: Are we talking about [Windows command prompt](https://www.google.com/search?name=f&hl=en&q=cmd.exe&gws_rd=ssl)?

Comment: yes exactly!! so that is how I should call the language? Sorry about delay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows you can run Mono executables without any tools:

> stress.exe /d=1

The reason is that C# and .NET was historically invented by Microsoft on Windows and only for Windows. It's the native platform. Mono is an open-source implementation of a C# compiler and .NET on other platforms (such as Linux).

You can even simply double click on `.exe` file in explorer if you don't need to pass command line arguments.

Also, you can run mono executable same way as you do on Linux:

> mono stress.exe /d=1

However, to be able to do this you should have Mono installation directory in system `PATH` environment variable (the `%PATH%`, analogous to `$PATH` on Linux).

You can add it temporarily with command `set`:

> set PATH=%PATH%;"c:\path\to\mono"

for example

> set PATH=%PATH%;"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mono\bin\"

This is analog to `export $PATH:</path/to/mono>` command on Linux.

The [Mono Command Prompt](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/install/windows/) does this before every launch.

You could also set up `PATH` permanently with a [builtin windows tool](https://www.google.com/search?name=f&hl=en&q=windows+set+path&gws_rd=ssl#hl=en&q=windows+add+to+path) or more convenient third party tools like [Rapid Environment Editor](http://www.rapidee.com/en/path-variable) (this will be analog to editing `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`)

You could also compile virtually any Mono code with [Microsoft Visual Studio](https://www.visualstudio.com/).

See also:

- [Mono -- Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mono_%28software%29)
- [Differences in development between .NET and Mono](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2783268/differences-in-development-between-net-and-mono)
- [.NET Framework](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework)
- [.NET Compiler Platform ("Roslyn")](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn)

Comment: thanks for the really complete answer!! too bad I can vote it up only once!!